# Grab Just the Month from date converted to string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, methods

I am trying to convert a date to a string and then grab the first 3 characters of the month so i can then use it in my view. So my date looks like this for example

```
23-07-2013
```

I have a method (may be totally wrong) but i cant get any output, though in irb this works. this is what i have

```
def date_mon(date)
 str = date.strftime("%e %B %Y") if date
 arr = str.split('-')
 arr[3-5]
end
```

Then in my view

```
<%= date_mon(p.created_at) %>
```

What i am trying to get to display in this case is

```
Jul
```

Any pointers on where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def date_mon(date)
  date.strftime("%b")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `split`, the array created has 2 positions. So you have to search for the 3 to 5 characters only on the first position of your array:

```
arr[0][3..5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could directly do

```
<%= p.created_at.strftime("%b") %>
```